# .htaccess allow deny some ip and allow from my site

Tags: .htaccess

i have a video file that want to block from viewing from other sites (so users can watch it just from my website) but i want also to allow some ips that can access it from everywhere

So to allow just some ips i use

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.111.111.111
allow from 111.111.111.112
...
```

it works great but i want also to allow all users that play video in my website

```
www.example.com
```

so can i exclude my website from deny from all, so if user visit it from mysite those rules will not work for him

Comment: This reads like you did not yet fully understand how networking or "websites" actually work. If a user requests your website then the request comes from some IP address. The term "just from my website" makes little sense then. Because if that refers to "everyone visiting / reading my website", then that would include _all_ IP addresses...

Comment: so is there a way then to exclude a vide from allow deny.
example video1.mp4 can be viewed by all ip-s and other files just from allow from ........

Comment: Obviously you can have different rules for different locations. That is documented, I suggest you read the documentation. What I tried to explain is that the separation of these two groups does not make any sense: 1. videos accessible to any ip address and 2. videos accessible by all visitors of your website which is all ip addresses too, because that is how the web works.